# jquery won't work in multi level dependency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

     $("#ddlprod").change(function() {

        var pk= $("#ddlprod").val();

        $.ajax({

        url: "ajaxprintdropdown.php",

        type: "POST",

        data: 'pk='+pk,

        timeout: 5000,

        success:  function(output) {                            

            $('#divtesting').show();    //works well            
            $('#divtesting').html(output);   //works well
        },


        }); 


     $("#ddltesting").change(function(){
        alert('a');    //not functioning at all
        var c= $("#ddltesting").val();
        alert(c);   //not functioning at all    
      });



     });
```

ajaxprintdropdown.php's output

```
<select name=ddltesting id=ddltesting >
<option value=''>--Select--</option>
<option value='test1'>bla for test1</option>
<option value='test2'>bla for test2</option>
</select>
```

Jquery not working for multi level dependency?
`$("#ddltesting").change(function(){` no response at all

Comment: See the bottom section of my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit***

@altCognito pointed out that live works with change events also. Then you can write

```
$("#ddltesting").live("change",function(){
    alert('a');    
    var c= $("#ddltesting").val();
    alert(c);   
});
```

From **[jQuery 1.4 Released](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14)**

> The change and submit events work
>   reliably across browsers for both
>   normal and live events. We override
>   the normal change and submit events in
>   Internet Explorer and replace them
>   with events that work identically to
>   the other browsers.

Try

```
$("#sampletextbox").val(c);
```

instead of

```
$("#sampletextbox").text(c);
```

Comment: -1 -- jQuery 1.4 live() handles change -- I'll knock it back up as soon as that's correct as 1.4 is the current version.

Comment: $("#ddltesting").live ( "change" , function(){   
   var c= $(this).val();
   $("#sampletextbox").text(c);   //live change bind works for var c, but not for #sampletextbox...
});